# GCC defines to VS

Tags: c, visual-studio-2012, gcc, c-preprocessor

I have the following code which compiles under GCC but throws the error 'expected an identifier' when attempting to compile under visual studio.

```
#define CALLING_CONVENTION WINAPI
#define PROXY_PROTOTYPE(FUNCTION_NAME) \
        void (FUNCTION_NAME)(void)
#define PROXY_FUNCTION(FUNCTION_NAME) \
        static CALLING_CONVENTION PROXY_PROTOTYPE(*_##FUNCTION_NAME) = NULL; \
        CALLING_CONVENTION PROXY_PROTOTYPE(FUNCTION_NAME) { \
            POP_EBP __asm__("jmp *__"#FUNCTION_NAME); \
        }
#define CALL_FUNCTION(FUNCTION_NAME) \
        static CALLING_CONVENTION FUNCTION_NAME##_(*_##FUNCTION_NAME) = NULL; \
        CALLING_CONVENTION FUNCTION_NAME##_(FUNCTION_NAME)
#define CALL_FUNCTION2(FUNCTION_RET, FUNCTION_NAME, FUNCTION_ARGS, ...) \
        static CALLING_CONVENTION FUNCTION_RET (*_##FUNCTION_NAME)(FUNCTION_ARGS) = NULL; \
        CALLING_CONVENTION FUNCTION_RET FUNCTION_NAME(FUNCTION_ARGS)



PROXY_FUNCTION(origFunc)
```

Obviously there is a difference in the compilers and their interpretation of the defines but I've no idea how to correct it for VS. I've tried looking up the error but its so generic it appears it could be any number of things. 
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure the problem isn't with the asm syntax? GCC and MSVC have completely different syntax for inline asm...

Answer (score 0):

@kusma already pointed out that GCC and MSVC had different inline asm syntax.

Moreover, MSVC for x64 doesn't support inline asm at all!

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4ks26t93%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

But this might not be a serious problem for you since we can run x86 (32 bit) programs on x64 Windows.  Just be careful when you configure your VC++ project.

Also be careful that they have different name decoration rules.

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zxk0tw93.aspx (_stdcall)